# How to analyze IE activity when opening a specific web page

Tags: python, html, internet-explorer, information-retrieval

I'd like to retrieve data from a specific webpage by using urllib library.
The problem is that in order to open this page some data should be sent to 
the server before. If I do it with IE, i need to update first some checkboxes and 
then press "display data" button, which opens the desired page.
Looking into the source code, I see that pressing "display data" submits some kind of 
form - there is no specific url address there. I cannot figure out by looking
at the code what paramaters are sent to the server...
I think that maybe the simpler way to do that would be to analyze the communication 
between the IE and the webserver after pressing the "display data" button.
If I could see explicitly what IE does, I could mimic it with urllib.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: When you "view source" on the page, what does the <form> say?  That filly defines the URL and the fields.  Please post the <form> from the page source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTML debugging proxy would be the best tool to use in this situation. As you're using IE, I recommend [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), as it is developed by Microsoft and automatically integrates with Internet Explorer through a plugin. I personally use Fiddler all the time, and it is a really helpful tool, as I'm building an app that mimics a user's browsing session with a website. Fiddler has really good debugging of request parameters, responses, and can even decode encrypted packets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *web debugging proxy* (e.g. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)) or a *browser addon* (e.g. [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647), [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966)) or a *packet sniffer* (e.g. [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)).